# App Store Server API: both transaction history and lookup customer order id return 404

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

We can get a customer’s transaction history through this (API)[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history]

`https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/{transactionid}`

and get purchase transactions through the customer order id per [wwdc21](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10175)

`https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/lookup/customer_order_id`

However, we got 404 with an empty response body for those two APIs and the `curl` response is

```
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 404
< server: daiquiri/3.0.0
< date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 12:03:24 GMT
< content-length: 0
< x-apple-jingle-correlation-key: EJJPZLFC7B3NTSO3PLZNUVVIXY
< x-apple-request-uuid: 2252fcac-a2f8-76d9-c9db-7af2da56a8be
< b3: 2252fcaca2f876d9c9db7af2da56a8be-ad831e3618544a32
< x-b3-traceid: 2252fcaca2f876d9c9db7af2da56a8be
< x-b3-spanid: ad831e3618544a32
< apple-seq: 0.0
< apple-tk: false
< apple-originating-system: CommerceGateway
< x-responding-instance: CommerceGateway:010116:::
< apple-timing-app: 0 ms
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< x-daiquiri-instance: daiquiri:45824002:st44p00it-hyhk15104701:7987:21HOTFIX14
<
```

How to debug this issue or anything am I missing?

**Update**

This API `inApps/v1/lookup` will be released per app store guys this year.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer, but just in case: if you're requesting a sandbox subscription, you should use the "https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/" base url as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi

Comment: And do you have the response's body, you should get more info on the 404: for example, `4040001` for `AccountNotFoundError`, `4040005` for `OriginalTransactionIdNotFoundError`, ... (cf. the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history, near the 404 part)

Comment: @romainsalles, we try to read the response body, however, the response body is empty. It is so weird.

Comment: @romainsalles, we test it with the product purchase so the api.storekit.itunes.apple.com is used

Comment: Indeed: `content-length: 0` in the response header. And yes, that's what I thought: If you've made all the work to generate the JWT, that means you have seen there were 2 base urls ^^' But... we never know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this API is only available in the sandbox environment for now:

[image]

[source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history)

That's why you have a generic `404` error without any response's body I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Missing this important discussion, my bad...

Comment: It seems that there is no customer order id in sandbox environment, so we cannot test this API `inApps/v1/lookup` in sandbox?